# an alternative for pretentious?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am not asking about a synonym

Google's result shows the meaning of pretentious as

> attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent,
>   culture, etc., than is actually possessed.

What would be the word to describe someone who *attempts to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc.*, but because he actually possesses it?

Is condescending or patronizing the right word here?

Comment: A *show-off*, perhaps?

Comment: @lawrence: what would be a more formal sounding synonym for this?

Comment: Your own term, *pretentious*, is 'more formal' and has a similar feel to *show-off*. The terms *condescending* and *patronizing* imply something about the person's attitude towards whoever they are communicating with.

Comment: What did you find in a thesaurus???

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition above, you could say *conceited, vain or narcissistic*

Condescending has a similar meaning but one out of those three given above fits your question better.

Answer (score 1):

He *puts on airs*

He's *full of himself*

He's *arrogant*

Informal and modern:

He *thinks he's all that*

(He might also be a snob.)

Answer (score 1):

How about the much under-used **[vainglorious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vainglorious)**

> adjective: having or showing too much pride in your abilities or
>   achievements

also **[Vainglory](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vainglory)**

> noun: excessive elation or pride over one's own achievements, abilities,
>   etc.; boastful vanity.

It does specify *too much* or *excessive* pride, but I think that might be the sense you are looking for.